# unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'zip' and 'zip'

Tags: python, python-3.x, unsupportedoperation

thanks for the answer before and I have changed it what Alperen suggested, but I have another problem, my code :

```
import sys
import os
import itertools
import os.path
import random
from PIL import Image
from svmutil import *

DIMENSION = 200
sys.path.append("../train/")
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()) + "/train" 
NEGATIVE = "negative"
POSITIVE = "positive"
CLASSES = [NEGATIVE, POSITIVE]

# libsvm constants
LINEAR = 0
RBF = 2

# Other
USE_LINEAR = False
IS_TUNING = False

def main():
    try:
        train, tune, test = getData(IS_TUNING)
        models = getModels(train)
        results = None
        if IS_TUNING:
            print ("!!! TUNING MODE !!!")
            results = classify(models, tune)
        else:
            results = classify(models, test)

        print
        totalCount = 0
        totalCorrect = 0
        for clazz in CLASSES:
            count, correct = results[clazz]
            totalCount += count
            totalCorrect += correct
            print ("%s %d %d %f") % (clazz, correct, count, (float(correct) / count))
        print ("%s %d %d %f") % ("Overall", totalCorrect, totalCount,(float(totalCorrect) / totalCount))

    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        return 5
def classify(models, dataSet):
    results = {}
    for trueClazz in CLASSES:
        count = 0
        correct = 0
        for item in dataSet[trueClazz]:
            predClazz, prob = predict(models, item)
            print ("%s,%s,%f") % (trueClazz, predClazz, prob)
            count += 1
            if trueClazz == predClazz: correct += 1
        results[trueClazz] = (count, correct)
    return results

def predict(models, item):
    maxProb = 0.0
    bestClass = ""
    for clazz, model in models.iteritems():
        prob = predictSingle(model, item)
        if prob > maxProb:
            maxProb = prob
            bestClass = clazz
    return (bestClass, maxProb)

def predictSingle(model, item):
    output = svm_predict([0], [item], model, "-q -b 1")
    prob = output[2][0][0]
    return prob

def getModels(trainingData):
    models = {}
    param = getParam(USE_LINEAR)
    for c in CLASSES:
        labels, data = getTrainingData(trainingData, c)
        prob = svm_problem(labels, data)
        m = svm_train(prob, param)
        models[c] = m
    return models

def getTrainingData(trainingData, clazz):
    labeledData = getLabeledDataVector(trainingData, clazz, 1)
    negClasses = [c for c in CLASSES if not c == clazz]
    for c in negClasses:
        ld = getLabeledDataVector(trainingData, c, -1)
        labeledData += ld
    random.shuffle(labeledData)
    unzipped = [list(t) for t in zip(*labeledData)]
    labels, data = unzipped[0], unzipped[1]
    return (labels, data)

def getParam(linear = True):
    param = svm_parameter("-q")
    param.probability = 1
    if(linear):
        param.kernel_type = LINEAR
        param.C = .01
    else:
        param.kernel_type = RBF
        param.C = .01
        param.gamma = .00000001
    return param

def getLabeledDataVector(dataset, clazz, label):
    data = dataset[clazz]
    labels = [label] * len(data)
    output = zip(labels, data)
    return output

def getData(generateTuningData):
    trainingData = {}
    tuneData = {}
    testData = {}

    for clazz in CLASSES:
        (train, tune, test) = buildTrainTestVectors(buildImageList(ROOT_DIR + clazz + "/"), generateTuningData)
        trainingData[clazz] = train
        tuneData[clazz] = tune
        testData[clazz] = test

    return (trainingData, tuneData, testData)

def buildImageList(dirName):
    imgs = [Image.open(dirName + fileName).resize((DIMENSION, DIMENSION)) for fileName in os.listdir(dirName)]
    imgs = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(img.getdata())) for img in imgs]
    return imgs

def buildTrainTestVectors(imgs, generateTuningData):
    # 70% for training, 30% for test.
    testSplit = int(.7 * len(imgs))
    baseTraining = imgs[:testSplit]
    test = imgs[testSplit:]

    training = None
    tuning = None
    if generateTuningData:
        # 50% of training for true training, 50% for tuning.
        tuneSplit = int(.5 * len(baseTraining))
        training = baseTraining[:tuneSplit]
        tuning = baseTraining[tuneSplit:]
    else:
        training = baseTraining

    return (training, tuning, test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   sys.exit(main())
```

and I got the new massage
[Klik this massage to see new error massage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JDBJ.png)
 What should I do? I have searched every answer but never make me get the answer. Now I use this code for my final project at university. I hope anyone can help me for this problem. But thank you for another last answer

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: the format like this ============= RESTART: C:\Users\abi\Documents\program coba\6.py =============
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' just that @hspandher

Comment: A stack trace should say the lines and rows. Could you add your full stack trace to your question? Don't use comments, please edit your question.

Comment: you can see the massage in the link that I have made

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Alperen, but as you said, there is another problem

Comment: @Alfarabialhaqi: Don't update the question with each fix, as it makes the answers posted so far seem nonsensical.

Comment: In any event, `getLabeledDataVector` is returning the result of `zip` without `list`-ifying it, while the code using it assumes it can `+=` it (likely written by or for Python 2, where `zip` returned `list`, not a lazy generator).

Comment: Please don't change your question again. You can edit for small changes or additions but don't change completely. This will cause some problems.

Comment: I added a suggestion in my answer but this can affect your code logic. I don't know what you are trying to do. So, I fixed the error, but it can break something.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

This lines causes the error:

```
labeledData += ld
```

`+=` operand doesn't work for `zip`s. You can change zips to list.

```
def getLabeledDataVector(dataset, clazz, label):
    ...
    return list(output)
```

Also, `unzipped` list can be empty, you should fix this line too(Thanks to **ShadowRanger** for comment):

```
labels, data = unzipped if unzipped else ([], [])
```

This changes probably will affect your code's logic. You should fix them on your own.

**BEFORE EDIT:**

In `getData(generateTuningData)` function, `ROOT_DIR + clazz` expression causes the error, because `ROOT_DIR` is `None`.

`sys.path.append` doesn't return anything(returns `None`).

You need to change your code as:

```
...
import os.path
...
sys.path.append("../train/") 
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()) + "/train/" # parent directory and "/train/"
...
```

I assumed `ROOT_DIR` is your **current working directory's parent + "/train/"**. If it is not, you can fix it.

Also, there may be other problems, but this solves `unsupported operand type(s)`.

Comment: `labels, data = 0, 0 if len(unzipped) < 1 else unzipped[0], unzipped[1]` has operator precedence issues, and will always fail with a `ValueError`, because it's creating a three-`tuple` and unpacking to two values. It's also wrong to assign it 0, when the logical results should be sequences (e.g. empty `tuple`). You probably want (simplifying the test for emptiness while I'm at it): `labels, data = unzipped if unzipped else ([], [])` or even simpler, `labels, data = unzipped or ([], [])`